# Adding space when combining 2 columns in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to combine two columns in my where clause:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, firstname, lastname FROM eymployees WHERE (firstname + ' ' + lastname) LIKE :username');
```

This is the error I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' . lastname) LIKE :username''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Is there a way I can add a space in between `firstname` and `lastname`?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You should use `=` instead of `LIKE` unless you specifically want the wildcard functionality. Otherwise, a user could enter `%` as their username which would match to everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CONCAT()` function

```
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, firstname, lastname FROM eymployees 
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)  LIKE :username');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, firstname, lastname FROM eymployees 
WHERE CONCAT(CONCAT(firstname, ' '), lastname)  LIKE :username');
```

if firstname and lastname is of char type, then use rtrim function

Comment: <?php
...
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, firstname, lastname FROM eymployees WHERE CONCAT(firstname, ' ',lastname) = :username');

Thank you - but the problem is ' ' -> I can't even run the code as I only get the error!